# Use json-rpc without full blockchain

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoind, ecash

So i want trying to use both bitcoin and bitcoin-abc json-rpc on raspberry pi but they will overload the whole pi when downloading and sync @ same time.

So is there anyway to use json-rpc without downloading and sync the whole blockchain or overload the raspberry pi?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use bitcoin core, you have to install blockchain. maybe you can use prune mode after its totally synced.

If you want to use JSON-RPC without installing the blockchain, I suggest you use electrum servers. You can send JSON-RPC commands without installing anything. You just connect to someone's server.

the commands not the same as bitcoin-core, for instance, you can't `createrawtransaction` but you can get any address balance or transaction details.

if you want to work with bitcoin-cash, You can connect to electrum bitcoin-cash servers.

check electrum protocol methods [here](https://electrumx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol-methods.html).

Comment: Pruning mode can be used while syncing, so that you still download the whole blockchain but you never have to store more than a few gigabytes at once.